# Нужно придумать алгоритм для задачи. Ограничение 1 секунда. Я пока реализовал только за O(NLM)

Tags: java, c++, python, алгоритм, структуры-данных

«Flood it!» — это простая, но крайне увлекательная игра. Правила её не очень затейливы: имеется прямоугольное поле, которое разбито на N строк и M столбцов. Перед началом игры каждая из N × M клеточек покрашена в один из К цветов. Прежде чем продолжать изложение условий игры, дадим несколько определений. Две клетки назовём соседними, если они имеют общую сторону. Несколько клеток назовём областью, если выполняются следующие условия:
между любыми двумя клетками области существует маршрут, проходящий по соседним клеткам этой области;
все клетки области окрашены в один цвет — цвет области;
ни одна клетка, не принадлежащая области, но соседствующая с ней, не окрашена в цвет области.
Цель игры состоит в захвате (овладевании) возможно большим числом клеток игрового поля. Изначально во владение игрока отдаётся область, содержащая верхнюю левую клетку. На каждом ходу игрок выбирает какой-либо цвет из К заданных и красит свои владения в этот цвет. Если перед ходом с одной их захваченных ранее клеток соседствует область, имеющая выбранный цвет, то игрок захватывает эту область.

К счастью, Вам не придётся составлять программу для моделирования всей игры. Вместо этого решите более простую задачу: на основании исходного состояния игрового поля и информации об L первых ходах игрока нарисуйте игровое поле, получившееся после этих ходов.

Формат входного файла

В первой строке через пробел заданы 4 целых положительных числа: N и M (1 ≤ N, M ≤ 10^3) — размеры поля, K (1 ≤ K ≤ 10^6) — число различных цветов и L (1 ≤ L ≤ 10^5) — длина последовательности ходов. Далее следует N строк, в каждой из которых через пробел записано по M чисел в диапазоне от 1 до K, где числа обозначают цвета начальной раскраски. В последней строке через пробел даны L чисел в диапазоне от 1 до K — последовательность ходов.
Формат выходного файла

Необходимо вывести N строк, в каждой из которых через пробел записано M чисел в диапазоне от 1 до K — состояние игрового поля по прошествии L заданных ходов.
input1
3 4 5 3
1 2 3 5
2 3 1 1
2 1 3 2
2 3 2
output1
2 2 2 5
2 2 1 1
2 1 3 2
input 2
2 5 6 2
1 3 3 3 6
2 4 6 3 4
3 1
output 2
1 1 1 1 6
2 4 6 1 4

Вот две реализации, которые я пытался сделать:
https://gist.github.com/StarP/392651efe795cfa786c7
https://gist.github.com/StarP/fa2888a70650c074f0a8

Comment: Ну так вперед! В чем проблема?! Придумывайте алгоритм, излагайте свои мысли, а мы Вам поможем. Какие уже мысли есть? Нет никаких? Тогда ничем не поможем.

Comment: У была идея с помощью поиска в ширину. Храним граничные клетки в очереди и с каждым новым цветом проверяем их соседей. Если сосед оказался этого цвета, то добавляем его в очередь. Если она перестала быть граничной, то удаляем с очереди. Но мой алгоритм работает за O(NML), а это слишком много, как понимаете.

Comment: @P.Star А почему вы считаете, что ваш алгоритм работает за O(NML) ? вы же на каждом ходе не все поле (NM) пересматриваете, а только соседние клетки с имеющимися. Если предположить, что мы начали с области из 1 клетки в углу, то на первом ходе вы проверите только 2е соседние клетки, это явно не NM (если конечно N или M >2 :) )

Comment: @Mike. Да, но в итоге у нас может получиться змейка из граничащих клеток(их количество NM/2) и мы будем смотреть для каждой клетки ее соседей(4) и сравнивать с цветом(это L раз).

Comment: @P.Star Ну скажем 3 соседа только, мы знаем с какой стороны мы пришли, но это конечно небольшое улучшение. хотя конечно хорошо бы как то более полно понимать геометрию области что бы делать меньше проверок. как ... пока хз

Comment: @Mike Я добавил две ссылки, как я пытался это сделать

Comment: «К счастью, Вам не придётся составлять программу для моделирования всей игры» — ну слава богу!

Answer (score 1):

Придумал следующий алгоритм: Сначала надо построить карту.

Берем матрицу `M*N` заполненную нулями - тут будут ID областей (Или храним ID области в структуре клетки).

Создаем расширяемый *массив списков*, сразу расчитываем скажем на N элементов. ID области - это индекс по которому лежит
список в этом массиве. Или можем сделать этот массив сразу `M*N`, что бы был с запасом на самый худший случай, когда все области по 1 клетке. В массиве изначально NULL, списки создаем по мере надобности.

Начинаем с 1й клетки, идем по горизонтали.

- Если у клетки ID 0 то назначаем ей первый свободный ID из массива списков и добавляем эту клетку в соответствующий список.
- Смотрим ее правого и нижнего соседей. Если сосед отличается по цвету - то ничего с ним не делаем.
- Если цвет соседа такой же и его ID=0, то ставим ему ID текущей клетки и добавляем в список.
- Если цвет соседа такой же и ID НЕ 0, то объединяем списки в один, а в *массиве списков* за обоими ID начинаем хранить адрес этого общего списка.

Замечание: у нас нет возврата к предыдущим клеткам, поэтому ID стоит менять только с 0 на новый. Тратить время на переписывание всей матрицы ID при слиянии списков не надо. (Тем более что у нас несколько ID по факту ссылаются на одну область.

При обработке ходов нам надо просмотреть соседей текущей области и если цвета равны - объединить списки.

По окончании ходов пройтись по полученному списку и перекрасить клетки для печати.

Иллюстрация работы построения карты. На входе матрица с 2 цветами:

```
1212 1212 1212
1112 2112 2112
1122 1111 2222
```

Проходы алгоритма по строкам. *Для наглядности* ID всех клеток сливаемых списков буду выставлять в одно значение. Списки нумерую 0-9-a-z. Матрица ID областей:

```
Прошли 1 строку    Прошли 2 строку   Прошли 3 строку
1235 679b cdfh     1215 67ab cdgh    121i 67jb cdgb
1435 8a9b egfh     1115 5aab bggh    111i ijjb bggb
                   11i5 jaak blmh    11ii jjjj bbbb
```

Можно попробовать строить карту частями. например в начале работы строим только на несколько клеток вправо и несколько клеток вниз. запоминаем оси по которым остановились. Но тогда при обработке хода нам придется пробегаться по присоединяемым спискам и если клетка граничит с одной из осей, то досчитывать еще какой то участок карты до тех пор, пока все клетки присоединяемых списков находятся вне края обработанного участка. Возможно это выйдет дороже, но для карты с небольшими областями может дать выигрыш